# Balupton Ajaxify html5 home page issue

Tags: ajax, html, back-button, ajaxify

I'm using Balupton's ajaxify gist: https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify

My home page contains links of posts in thumbs etc. The post content is loading in the ajax container.So the homepage content stays on page while the other content loads in the container div.

It works well while i am at the home page and click a post link the content of the post loads without problem in the container. Now if i hit the browser's back button the home page loads in the container so i have the home page's content in two different divs. Is it possible to exclude the home page from loading in the container? Has anyone done this before?

Comment: @rdck Yes I got it working. It was a markup issue. I had to put all elements i wanted to be present on all pages, outside the ajax container. That way everything else stays on the page while the new content is loading inside the ajax container.